# Why is ":" in the link red?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I'm very confused why is "**:**" in the link red and after that the text is in *italics*, script is working, but why is it like that? Is it problem of VS Code or my mistake? Thank you for your answers.

[image: CODE]

```html
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("spaces").href="https://www.w3schools.com"'>Change site to w3schools</button>

                                                                            ^
                                                                            └ This color is red
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the Issues/Errors window?

Comment: If it is not showing any compile or runtime error, the culprit could be some VS code formatter extension.

Comment: Note: inline JS should be avoided in 2022. I don't know where that example came from but any issues you're having could (most likely) be avoided by separating your markup from your JS code.

Comment: @Dai I don't see some error or issue.

Comment: @Andy I did that and it doesn't show anymore! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Error with two slashes (//) after that (:). Try write `:\//` or `:\/\/`

Comment: I tried, but there is always the error.